# How To get the specific child of the parent div using by DOM get method?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to access the specific child by class name but it's not working it gives me all inner html used in ul?

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].innerHTML;
console.log(element);
```

```html
  <ul id="list" class="inner">
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <li><a href="" class="hom" id="hoo">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Classes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Teachers</a></li>
    <button ><a href="" id="btn-1" >Join class</a></button>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Also note that ONLY `li` can be children of a `ul....anything else is invalid HTML.

Comment: AND `button` elements cannot contain links and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array with all the `elements` that have said class. `document.getElementsByClassName('inner')[0]` would just be selecting the first and only element with such class (Your `ul`).

If you need to access a specific child of that element, you would need to use the `children` property and then you can use any index that matches an existing child.

```js
var element=document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].children[0].innerHTML;
console.log(element);
```

```html
<ul id="list" class="inner">
                     <p>paragraph</p>
                     <li><a href="" class="hom" id="hoo">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                     <li><a href="">Classes</a></li>
                     <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                     <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
                     <li><a href="">Teachers</a></li>
                     <button ><a href="" id="btn-1" >Join class</a></button>
              </ul>
       </nav>
```

I would advise against `document.getElementsByClassName` and just use `document.querySelector('.inner')` instead to select the element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getElementsByClassName` you can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to easily target the paragraphs innerHTML.

See example below:

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".inner p").innerHTML;

console.log(element);
```

```html
<ul id="list" class="inner">
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <li><a href="" class="hom" id="hoo">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Classes</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Teachers</a></li>
  <button><a href="" id="btn-1" >Join class</a></button>
</ul>
</nav>
```